# Add data from other table to form + Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, forms, symfony, doctrine

I have a table users with different fields in it. And I also have a table players with a FK user_id in it (along other fields).

Now I have a registerForm to create a user, but I would also like to add a field for a player.

This is my form now:

```
$builder
    ->add('userFirstname', 'text', [
        'label' => 'Given name',
        'attr'  => [
            'placeholder' => 'Enter your given name.',
        ],
    ])
    ->add('userSurname', 'text', [
        'label' => 'Family name',
        'attr'  => ['placeholder' => 'Enter your family name.'],
    ])
    ->add('userType', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array('E' => 'ENTHOUSIAST', 'P' => 'PLAYER', 'T' => 'TRAINER'),
        'label'         => 'User Type',
        'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'User Type')
    ))
    ->add('player')
    ->add('userUsername', 'text', [
        'label' => 'Username',
        'attr'  => ['placeholder' => 'Enter a username.'],
    ])
    ->add('userEmail', 'email', [
        'label' => 'Email address',
        'attr'  => ['placeholder' => 'Enter your email address.'],
    ])
    ->add('userPassword', 'repeated', [
        'type'           => 'password',
        'first_name'     => 'password',
        'first_options'  => [
            'label' => 'Password',
            'attr'  => ['placeholder' => 'Enter a password.'],
        ],
        'second_name'    => 'confirm',
        'second_options' => [
            'label' => 'Password (repeat)',
            'attr'  => ['placeholder' => 'Repeat the password.'],
        ],
        'invalid_message' => 'The passwords are not identical.',
    ])
    ->add('btn_register', 'submit', [
        'label' => 'Register',
    ])
;
```

In my players table I have 'player_birthyear'. How can I add this to my form? I already tried to add player.birthyear to my Form but didn't work.

**UPDATE:**
My **Users** entities class:

```
/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_users_roles1_idx", columns={"role_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_username", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userUsername;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_firstname", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userFirstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_surname", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userSurname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_email", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userEmail;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_type", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $userType;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_password", type="string", length=60, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userPassword;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_salt", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userSalt;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_token", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $userToken;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_created", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $userCreated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_modified", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userModified;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_deleted", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userDeleted;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_lastlogin", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userLastlogin;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_confirmed", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userConfirmed;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_locked", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userLocked;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $userId;

    /**
     * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="role_id")
     * })
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_follows_teams",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", referencedColumnName="team_id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $team;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_follows_competitions",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="competition_id", referencedColumnName="competition_id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $competition;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->team = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->competition = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Set userUsername
     *
     * @param string $userUsername
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserUsername($userUsername)
    {
        $this->userUsername = $userUsername;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userUsername
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserUsername()
    {
        return $this->userUsername;
    }

    /**
     * Set userFirstname
     *
     * @param string $userFirstname
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserFirstname($userFirstname)
    {
        $this->userFirstname = $userFirstname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userFirstname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserFirstname()
    {
        return $this->userFirstname;
    }

    /**
     * Set userSurname
     *
     * @param string $userSurname
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserSurname($userSurname)
    {
        $this->userSurname = $userSurname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userSurname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserSurname()
    {
        return $this->userSurname;
    }

    /**
     * Set userEmail
     *
     * @param string $userEmail
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserEmail($userEmail)
    {
        $this->userEmail = $userEmail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userEmail
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserEmail()
    {
        return $this->userEmail;
    }

    /**
     * Set userType
     *
     * @param string $userType
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserType($userType)
    {
        $this->userType = $userType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userType
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserType()
    {
        return $this->userType;
    }

    /**
     * Set userPassword
     *
     * @param string $userPassword
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserPassword($userPassword)
    {
        $this->userPassword = $userPassword;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userPassword
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserPassword()
    {
        return $this->userPassword;
    }

    /**
     * Set userSalt
     *
     * @param string $userSalt
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserSalt($userSalt)
    {
        $this->userSalt = $userSalt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userSalt
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserSalt()
    {
        return $this->userSalt;
    }

    /**
     * Set userToken
     *
     * @param string $userToken
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserToken($userToken)
    {
        $this->userToken = $userToken;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userToken
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserToken()
    {
        return $this->userToken;
    }

    /**
     * Set userCreated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userCreated
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserCreated($userCreated)
    {
        $this->userCreated = $userCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userCreated
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUserCreated()
    {
        return $this->userCreated;
    }

    /**
     * Set userModified
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userModified
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserModified($userModified)
    {
        $this->userModified = $userModified;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userModified
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUserModified()
    {
        return $this->userModified;
    }

    /**
     * Set userDeleted
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userDeleted
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserDeleted($userDeleted)
    {
        $this->userDeleted = $userDeleted;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userDeleted
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUserDeleted()
    {
        return $this->userDeleted;
    }

    /**
     * Set userLastlogin
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userLastlogin
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserLastlogin($userLastlogin)
    {
        $this->userLastlogin = $userLastlogin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userLastlogin
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUserLastlogin()
    {
        return $this->userLastlogin;
    }

    /**
     * Set userConfirmed
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userConfirmed
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserConfirmed($userConfirmed)
    {
        $this->userConfirmed = $userConfirmed;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userConfirmed
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUserConfirmed()
    {
        return $this->userConfirmed;
    }

    /**
     * Set userLocked
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userLocked
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserLocked($userLocked)
    {
        $this->userLocked = $userLocked;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userLocked
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUserLocked()
    {
        return $this->userLocked;
    }

    /**
     * Get userId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles $role
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setRole(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles $role = null)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles 
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * Add team
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team
     * @return Users
     */
    public function addTeam(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team)
    {
        $this->team[] = $team;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove team
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team
     */
    public function removeTeam(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team)
    {
        $this->team->removeElement($team);
    }

    /**
     * Get team
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getTeam()
    {
        return $this->team;
    }

    /**
     * Add competition
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions $competition
     * @return Users
     */
    public function addCompetition(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions $competition)
    {
        $this->competition[] = $competition;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove competition
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions $competition
     */
    public function removeCompetition(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions $competition)
    {
        $this->competition->removeElement($competition);
    }

    /**
     * Get competition
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCompetition()
    {
        return $this->competition;
    }
}
```

My **Players** entities class:

```
/**
 * Players
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="players", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_players_users1_idx", columns={"user_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_players_teams1_idx", columns={"team_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_players_myteam1_idx", columns={"myteam_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Players
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $playerName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_licensenumber", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $playerLicensenumber;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_position", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $playerPosition;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_birthyear", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $playerBirthyear;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $playerId;

    /**
     * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="myteam_id", referencedColumnName="myteam_id")
     * })
     */
    private $myteam;

    /**
     * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", referencedColumnName="team_id")
     * })
     */
    private $team;

    /**
     * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     * })
     */
    private $user;



    /**
     * Set playerName
     *
     * @param string $playerName
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setPlayerName($playerName)
    {
        $this->playerName = $playerName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPlayerName()
    {
        return $this->playerName;
    }

    /**
     * Set playerLicensenumber
     *
     * @param string $playerLicensenumber
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setPlayerLicensenumber($playerLicensenumber)
    {
        $this->playerLicensenumber = $playerLicensenumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerLicensenumber
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPlayerLicensenumber()
    {
        return $this->playerLicensenumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set playerPosition
     *
     * @param string $playerPosition
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setPlayerPosition($playerPosition)
    {
        $this->playerPosition = $playerPosition;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerPosition
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPlayerPosition()
    {
        return $this->playerPosition;
    }

    /**
     * Set playerBirthyear
     *
     * @param \DateTime $playerBirthyear
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setPlayerBirthyear($playerBirthyear)
    {
        $this->playerBirthyear = $playerBirthyear;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerBirthyear
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getPlayerBirthyear()
    {
        return $this->playerBirthyear;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPlayerId()
    {
        return $this->playerId;
    }

    /**
     * Set myteam
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam $myteam
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setMyteam(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam $myteam = null)
    {
        $this->myteam = $myteam;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get myteam
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam 
     */
    public function getMyteam()
    {
        return $this->myteam;
    }

    /**
     * Set team
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setTeam(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team = null)
    {
        $this->team = $team;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get team
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams 
     */
    public function getTeam()
    {
        return $this->team;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users $user
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setUser(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

When I try add a player field I get this error:

```
Neither the property "player" nor one of the methods "getPlayer()", "isPlayer()", "hasPlayer()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users".
```

**UPDATE 2:**
And I also have a FK in my players table 'team_id'. So when I create a user I would like to also select a team. So what I want is a list from all the teams in the database and set is as a choice field type in my Form. Do you know how I can place that in my formtype?

**UPDATE 3:**

I've added the following to my Users entity class:

```
    private $player;

/**
 * Get player
 *
 * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players
 */
public function getPlayer() {
    return $this->player;
}
/**
 * Set player
 *
 * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players $player
 * @return Users
 */
public function setPlayer(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players $player){
    $this->player = $player;
}
```

In my formtype I've added:

```
->add('player')
```

Now in my form I want to do the following:

```
{{ form_label(registerForm.player.playerLicensenumber, label|default(),
```

Because in my Players entity class I have playerLicensenumber but I always get this error:

```
Method "playerLicensenumber" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in VolleyScoutBundle:User:register.html.twig at line 57
```

**UPDATE 4:**
Is this a good solution:
Added this to my register form:

```
->add('player', new PlayerType())
```

And in my playertype I have the fields from player table.

Comment: Could you post a code sample of your entities please ?

Comment: I updated my begin post!

Comment: So your user registers and can select a player in the form ? Try just adding a 'player' field : "->add('player')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a setter and a getter for your "player" field in your User entity.

```
public function getPlayer() {
    return $this->player;
}

public function setPlayer(\Path\to\player\entity $player){
    $this->player = $player;
}
```

For the team list in your form, you have to add an "entity" field type. Here are the docs for more info : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: Thanks for the help! I updated my begin post, do you know that solution too?

Comment: Thanks! But I still get a problem with the first question. Updated my begin post..

Comment: Updated, just added player to my form

Comment: I've put a solution in my begin post (UPDATE 4). Is this a good solution or bad code?

Comment: Yes, actually that's the right way to do it :) You should read this chapter http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html to have more info about how to do it properly